# Android studio VOLUME UP/DOWN/MUTE event didn't triggered

Tags: java, android, audio, apk, android-tv

i'm trying to capture the Volume UP/ Down and Muted remote's events on an Android Studio Activity in a WebView (without any player active).

I already tryed to Override onKeyDown, OnKeyLongPress and dispatchKeyEvent but I'm able to capture all remote's button except the audio buttons.

Example:

```
@SuppressLint("RestrictedApi")
@Override
public boolean dispatchKeyEvent(KeyEvent event) {
    int action = event.getAction();
    int keyCode = event.getKeyCode();
    switch (keyCode) {
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_UP:
            if (action == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                //todo
            }
            return true;
        case KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_DOWN:
            if (action == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                //todo
            }
            return true;
        default:
            return super.dispatchKeyEvent(event);
    }
}
```

The function is triggered by all buttons except audio buttons.
Could anyone help me?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can use different approach to catch volume change by listening to the android.media.VOLUME_CHANGED_ACTION broadcast.